# Simplifying this Boolean Expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have to simplify A+C'+B'CD but I don't see how.

I had to deduce the expression starting from a logic diagram in which two AND gates were used for the B'CD part. Seeing the diagram all I can think of is to use one AND gate instead of two, but I don't see how the actual boolean expression can be simplified.

Comment: Try to get the product of sum expression from K-map

Answer (score 1):

Using the property $X+YZ = (X+Y)(X+Z)$, you can silmplify $C' + B'CD$ as $C' + B'D$.